# speed up if statement in data table on r

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I have mem_ord (1561464ods of 74 variables). SITE_JOIN_DATE is the date type and SITE_JOIN_DATE is trying to divide the user type according to the condition. But it was too slow to see the results. The if conditional is too slow. How can I increase the speed? I can also use multiple cores.

```
   mem_ord_by_user <- mem_ord[, list(
      AF_SITE_JOIN_DT = Sys.Date() - SITE_JOIN_DATE,
      DAY_PAY_CNT = .N,
      DAY_TOT_PRICE = .SD[, sum(TOT_PAY_PRICE)],
      USER_TYPE = .SD[
        ,if(SITE_JOIN_DATE > '2017-07-17' && SITE_JOIN_DATE < '2017-08-05' && !is.na(SITE_JOIN_DATE)){
          'event_joiner'
        }else if((SITE_JOIN_DATE <= '2017-07-17' || SITE_JOIN_DATE >= '2017-08-05') && !is.na(SITE_JOIN_DATE)){
          'no_event_joiner'
        }else{
          'null_user'
        }]
    ),
    by=list(ORD_DT, CUSTOMER_NUM), 
    .SDcols = c('TOT_PAY_PRICE', 'SITE_JOIN_DATE')]
```

Comment: The key value in mem_ord is 
setkeyv(mem_ord, c('ORD_DT', 'CUSTOMER_NUM')) .
This can also be changed.

Comment: can you give example data?

Comment: Would it make a difference speedwise if you used a nested `ifelse()` construct instead of `if()... else if()`?

Comment: I can not create example data.

Comment: is `SITE_JOIN_DATE` in Date format?

Comment: yes!!  I'm writing a lubridate package!

Comment: how does your desired output look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
require(data.table)
N <- 10
dateSeq <- seq(as.Date('2017/07/01'), Sys.Date(), by="day")
set.seed(120)
mem_ord <- data.table(SITE_JOIN_DATE = sample(dateSeq, N, replace=T),
                      TOT_PAY_PRICE = rnorm(N),
                      ORD_DT = sample(dateSeq, N, replace=T),
                      CUSTOMER_NUM = sample(1:1000, N, replace=T))

mem_ord[sample(1:.N, 2), SITE_JOIN_DATE := NA]
mem_ord
#    SITE_JOIN_DATE TOT_PAY_PRICE     ORD_DT CUSTOMER_NUM
# 1:     2017-08-05    0.22596353 2017-07-14          975
# 2:           <NA>   -0.90504565 2017-08-17          124
# 3:     2017-08-01    1.70870936 2017-09-25          382
# 4:     2017-09-10    0.09849052 2017-09-22          890
# 5:     2017-07-18    0.79617909 2017-08-02          499
# 6:           <NA>    0.38020124 2017-08-06          902
# 7:     2017-09-27    0.46077825 2017-09-09          367
# 8:     2017-07-09    0.49886281 2017-08-08          907
# 9:     2017-09-15   -1.35021861 2017-07-18          906
# 10:     2017-09-21   -0.53256174 2017-09-01          560

d1 <- as.Date('2017-07-17')
d2 <- as.Date('2017-08-05')
mem_ord[, USER_TYPE := ifelse(SITE_JOIN_DATE > d1 & SITE_JOIN_DATE < d2,
                              "event_joiner", "no_event_joiner")]
mem_ord[is.na(USER_TYPE), USER_TYPE := "null_user"]
mem_ord[, .N ,keyby = USER_TYPE]
#          USER_TYPE N
# 1:    event_joiner 2
# 2: no_event_joiner 6
# 3:       null_user 2

mem_ord_by_user <- mem_ord[, list(
  AF_SITE_JOIN_DT = Sys.Date() - SITE_JOIN_DATE,
  DAY_PAY_CNT = .N,
  DAY_TOT_PRICE = sum(TOT_PAY_PRICE),
  USER_TYPE = USER_TYPE),
by=list(ORD_DT, CUSTOMER_NUM, SITE_JOIN_DATE)]

mem_ord_by_user
# ORD_DT CUSTOMER_NUM SITE_JOIN_DATE AF_SITE_JOIN_DT DAY_PAY_CNT DAY_TOT_PRICE       USER_TYPE
# 1: 2017-07-14          975     2017-08-05         54 days           1    0.22596353 no_event_joiner
# 2: 2017-08-17          124           <NA>         NA days           1   -0.90504565       null_user
# 3: 2017-09-25          382     2017-08-01         58 days           1    1.70870936    event_joiner
# 4: 2017-09-22          890     2017-09-10         18 days           1    0.09849052 no_event_joiner
# 5: 2017-08-02          499     2017-07-18         72 days           1    0.79617909    event_joiner
# 6: 2017-08-06          902           <NA>         NA days           1    0.38020124       null_user
# 7: 2017-09-09          367     2017-09-27          1 days           1    0.46077825 no_event_joiner
# 8: 2017-08-08          907     2017-07-09         81 days           1    0.49886281 no_event_joiner
# 9: 2017-07-18          906     2017-09-15         13 days           1   -1.35021861 no_event_joiner
10: 2017-09-01          560     2017-09-21          7 days           1   -0.53256174 no_event_joiner
```

Comment: Thank you. I was worried about the := method in the data table, but I did not know what to do. As you can see above, the speed is much faster.